# Performing a prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

2016-01-19 23:21:15.132 Test2[86049:25427867] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'gameSegue''

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gameSegue"{
        let gameViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
        gameViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("gameSegue", sender: gameViewController)
    }
}

    viewController = MainMenuViewController()
    let segue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "gameSegue", source: MainMenuViewController(), destination: GameViewController())
    viewController.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: self)
```

I get the error above whenever i call the prepareForSegue function

Comment: Check [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22has+no+segue+with+identifier%22+NSInvalidArgumentException+%5Bswift%5D).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
let gameViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
gameViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("gameSegue", sender: gameViewController)


viewController = MainMenuViewController()
let segue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "gameSegue", source: MainMenuViewController(), destination: GameViewController())
viewController.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: self)
```

With

```
let detailedView = GameViewController()
    if let detailedView = segue.destinationViewController as? GameViewController {
       // Do whatever passing of parameters here.         
    }
```

Add the segue code to where you will invoke.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("gameSegue", sender: nil)
```

Comment: In your main storyboard, under Attributes Inspector, did you set gameSegue under the Identifier?

Comment: I did set it to that

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to indicate that you want to either cascade two segues (with the same name on both controller) or you are trying to redirect to a different controller.

Is this really what you are trying to do ?

currentController -> "gameSegue" -> gameViewController -> "gameSegue" -> ???

When a segue is triggered (e.g. from the storyboard), both the prepareForSegue and performSegueWithIdentifier are called automatically.  You don't have to call performSegueWithIdentifier yourself.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is go from my mainmenuviewcontroller to my gameviewcontroller. I'm trying to do this through SpriteKit

Comment: I'm trying to segue when I tap on the screen

Comment: If that segue is being triggered, there should be nothing to do in prepareForSegue.   You should remove the whole function.  If you're still getting an error after that, it will be a different error and probably the root cause of the problem.   Right now, this code IS the source of the error you're seeing and is potentially masking the problem (if there is one)